# Unexpected sparse matrix after CountVectorizer transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, countvectorizer

I'm new at NLTK and am having trouble with creating a classifier for reviews.
[image]
[image]

I am unable to understand how the shape of the transformed data is a 1*1 sparse matrix when the data passed as input was of shape (10000,1)
I have processed the original review data a bit. Like removing stop words, stemming and removing punctuations.

I need help with where I'm going wrong and please let me know if any more details are needed to find the problem.

Comment: Please show a few lines from `X_train1`.

Comment: I've edit the question and added a sample of X_train1 @andrew_reece

Comment: It looks like `X_train1` is a Pandas data frame with a column `Description`.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `X_train1` is actually a Pandas data frame, based on the formatting of your screenshot.  The problem is that `Description` is a column of lists of words (probably of unequal lengths).  Something like this:

```
X = np.array([['alpha','beta'],['theta','theta','gamma'],['delta','delta']])
X_train1 = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=["Description"])

X_train1
             Description
0          [alpha, beta]
1  [theta, theta, gamma]
2         [delta, delta]

X_train1.shape # (3,1)
```

So you have 10,000 rows of lists of words (with shape `(nrow, 1)`).
But `CountVectorizer` (assuming you're using the `sklearn` class) takes an array of documents.  From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> **CountVectorizer**: Convert a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts

More specifically, consider the argument definition to `fit()`:

> **raw_documents**: An iterable which yields either str, unicode or file objects.

If you just try and pass in `X_train1`, you're not providing the expected input - you're passing in a data frame containing a column containing list objects of strings.  You should expect to get weird output doing that.

Assuming each row in `X_train1` represents a document, try joining the word list on each row, then pass to `CountVectorizer`:

```
X = X_train1.Description.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row))
ctvec = CountVectorizer()
ctvec.fit_transform(X) # combine fit(X) and transform(X)
```

Output:

```
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

This output is more in line with the intended input.